# Martial arts show with a character named Metsu

Tags: shura-no-toki

The anime was based on the unarmed fighting style. The main protagonist was *Metsu*. I forgot the first name. it showed three different descendants in the arc. One was the era of the *Shinsengumi*. And two others, I can't remember.

Answer (score 4):

You are very likely looking for [Shura no Toki](http://anidb.net/perl-bin/animedb.pl?show=anime&aid=1663).

> Legends tell of an invincible martial art known as Mutsu Enmei-Ryu, an **unarmed style** that allows the user to defeat any number of armed opponents using incredible speed and strength. This is the story of three generations of those who bear the name **Mutsu**, and their encounters and battles with the strongest fighters of their era.

The AniDB entry is tagged with *Shinsengumi*.